# Get back line associated with aggrigate e.g. min

Tags: mysql, sql, min

Hi I'm wondering if there is a way to get back information from a line associated with a min. So in the be following example I would like to simply get back the min(date) and associated piece of information for each customer.

```
   Cust_id            Date              information
   -----------------------------------------------------
    12345           2015-04-03          blue hat 
    12345           2015-04-05          red scarf
    12345           2015-04-02          blue hat
    12345           2015-04-08          yellow submarine
    54321           2015-04-12          yellow submarine
```

The result would look like this:

```
   Cust_id            Date              information
   -----------------------------------------------------
    12345           2015-04-02          blue hat 
    54321           2015-04-12          yellow submarine
```

At the moment, to get this out I would use temp table or sub-query to get out the min(date) for each customer and join back onto table on that date.

```
SELECT cust_id
,      MIN(date)
INTO   #TempTable
FROM   dataset
GROUP BY cust_id


SELECT cust_id
,      date
,      information
FROM dataset A INNER JOIN #TempTable B ON A.cust_id = B.cust_id 
                                       AND A.date = B.date
```

This approach works, but I imagine there is a much cleaner and simpler way to do it within the one pull. Perhaps a function I am not aware of?

Any help, advice, examples or sources on this would be very much appreciated,

Thanks,

Bob

Comment: Yep, there is, select the mins in a subquery and in the outer query join back to your main table. There are quite a few topics here on SO that can give you sample code if necessary.

Comment: Using a temporary or a derived table is the way to go with MySQL. Other databases have more options, like `distinct on` in Postgresql or using window functions (in many databases).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a temporary table, get the minimums in a subquery and in the outer query join back to your main table:

```
SELECT A.cust_id
,      A.date
,      A.information
FROM dataset A
INNER JOIN (SELECT cust_id
            ,      MIN(date) as mindate
            FROM   dataset
            GROUP BY cust_id
            ) B ON A.cust_id = B.cust_id AND A.date = B.mindate
```

Comment: I use subqueries as well. I just thought that I have have been doing things in an overly convoluted way by using subqueries/temptables (the logical idea is essentially the same for both) . Thanks for the answers everyone, I can stop wondering about it now :).

Comment: In case of subqueries MySQL may or may not create a temporary table, so it has more options. There is another way to do this in MySQL, however, that relies on a non-standard `group by` clause, specific config settings of MySQL, and on an undocumented implementation detail that could change without any notice, so I discourage you to go down that route.